# C++ Read machine GUID via RegGetValue

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

So today, i've been trying to get a MachineGuid value from registry in C++ via RegGetValue.

RegGetValue works fine for me on almost every other value i try to read in the registry, but does not work with MachineGuid for some reason (output = nothing).

Does anyone have any idea on how to approach this? How do i retreive it correctly?(Preferably string)
Sorry if this is a noob-ish question, I just don't know what else to do at this point.
Thanks!

```
#define BUFFER 8192
int main{
char value[255];
DWORD BufferSize = BUFFER;
RegGetValueA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", "MachineGuid", RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&value, &BufferSize);
std::cout << value << std::endl; // Returns absolutely nothing.
system("pause");

}
```

Comment: You are lying to the OS about your buffer size. However I am not sure that hurts you here.

Comment: Check the return value, and remember that registry functions return 0 on success.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however as I said, it works perfectly fine when i try to read other registry values. It actually outputs the values successfully. Doesn't work with MachineGuid for some reason....

Comment: Could be a permission problem.

Comment: And that's why you check the return value, that way you find out what (if anything) the function thinks is wrong in this particular case. If it turns out the call succeeds but there is still no output (particularly by returned buffer size) then something is very weird.

Comment: [Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing your `value` buffer to `RegGetValueA()` correctly.  Get rid of the `&` operator (and the type-cast).  Let the array decay into a pointer naturally.

More importantly, you need to pass the *correct* buffer size, in bytes.  You are allocating only 255 bytes, but are telling `RegGetValueA()` that `value` has 8192 bytes available, which is a lie.  Even though `MachineGuid` will return only 37 bytes on success, you should not lie to the API.

Also, you need to check the return value of `RegGetValueA()` to see whether it succeeds or fails, and if it fails then you can find out WHY it fails.

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    char value[255];
    DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(value);
    LONG res = RegGetValueA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", "MachineGuid", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, value, &BufferSize);
    if (res == 0)
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;

        /* alternatively:
        std::cout.write(value, BufferSize-1); // -1 to ignore the null terminator
        std::cout << std::endl;
        */
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Error: " << res << std::endl;

    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```